# How can I reduce the number of rewrite rules?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, regex

I'm building a robust filtering system for my WordPress site, and I really want to have pretty permalinks for the resulting URLs. But because I'm offering a large amount of different filtering options, the different rules required for rewriting are getting out of control. I'm currently running at 80 rewrite rules, with no idea of knowing if this is going to badly impact my site's performance (though I guess the real answer to *that* question is "it depends").

The problem is that every time I add a new filter choice, it doubles the amount of rules unless I can catch it in a regular expression. **How can I simplify rewrite rules with these requirements?**

- 3 taxonomies can be included in any combination and any order, but must always come before any of the below mention additional URL segments. URLs without *any* of these taxonomies are also allowed. Taxonomies are `genre`, `artist` and the built-in `tag`. URL segments looks like
  `/genre/neurofunk/tag/bassdrive-xposure-show/artist/ben-xo+dj-liquid/`;
- To show posts within a specific date range, two URL segments can be included to set a date range WHERE clause, like `/20120826/20140513/`;
- Ordering by built-in columns and custom `meta_value`s is possible by using the `/by/` URL segment, followed by the key. To be able to distinct between built-in and custom keys, a prefixed underscore is used: `/by/comment_count/` vs. `/by/_downloads/`;
- Since default ordering is DESC, I include `/asc/` as URL segment when I want to sort that way;
- To ensure working pagination, I duplicated each rule to include a `/page/` segment.

**My rewrite rules**

```
function tjnz_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $rules = array(
        // with daterange + 3 params + orderby meta
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(_.+?)\/asc\/page\/([0-9])\/?$' => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(9) . '&order=asc&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(10),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(_.+?)\/asc\/?$'                => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(9) . '&order=asc',
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(_.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'      => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(9) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(10),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(_.+?)\/?$'                     => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(9),
        // with daterange + 3 params + orderby native
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(.+?)\/asc\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'  => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(9) . '&order=asc&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(10),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(.+?)\/asc\/?$'                 => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(9) . '&order=asc',
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'       => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(9) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(10),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(.+?)\/?$'                      => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(9),
        // with daterange + 3 params w/o orderby
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'                  => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(9),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/?$'                                 => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8),

        // no daterange + 3 params + orderby meta
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(_.+?)\/asc\/page\/([0-9])\/?$' => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&order=asc&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(_.+?)\/asc\/?$'                => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&order=asc',
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(_.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'      => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(_.+?)\/?$'                     => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7),
        // no daterange + 3 params + orderby native
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(.+?)\/asc\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'  => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&order=asc&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(.+?)\/asc\/?$'                 => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&order=asc',
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'       => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(.+?)\/?$'                      => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7),
        // no daterange + 3 params w/o orderby
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'                  => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/?$'                                 => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6),

        // with daterange + 2 params + orderby meta
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(_.+?)\/asc\/page\/([0-9])\/?$' => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&order=asc&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(_.+?)\/asc\/?$'                => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&order=asc',
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(_.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'      => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(_.+?)\/?$'                     => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7),
        // with daterange + 2 params + orderby native
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(.+?)\/asc\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'  => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&order=asc&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(.+?)\/asc\/?$'                 => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&order=asc',
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'       => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(8),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(.+?)\/?$'                      => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7),
        // with daterange + 2 params w/o orderby
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'                  => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(7),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/?$'                                 => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6),

        // no daterange + 2 params + orderby meta
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(_.+?)\/asc\/page\/([0-9])\/?$' => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&order=asc&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(_.+?)\/asc\/?$'                => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&order=asc',
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(_.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'      => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(_.+?)\/?$'                     => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5),
        // no daterange + 2 params + orderby native
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(.+?)\/asc\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'  => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&order=asc&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(.+?)\/asc\/?$'                 => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&order=asc',
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'       => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(.+?)\/?$'                      => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5),
        // no daterange + 2 params w/o orderby
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'                  => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/?$'                                 => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5),

        // with daterange + 1 param + orderby meta
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(_.+?)\/asc\/page\/([0-9])\/?$' => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&order=asc&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(_.+?)\/asc\/?$'                => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&order=asc',
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(_.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'      => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(_.+?)\/?$'                     => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5),
        // with daterange + 1 param + orderby native
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(.+?)\/asc\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'  => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&order=asc&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(.+?)\/asc\/?$'                 => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&order=asc',
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'       => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(6),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(.+?)\/?$'                      => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5),
        // with daterange + 1 param w/o orderby
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'                  => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(5),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+)\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/?$'                                  => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4),

        // no daterange + 1 param + orderby meta
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(_.+?)\/asc\/page\/([0-9])\/?$' => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&order=asc&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(_.+?)\/asc\/?$'                => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&order=asc',
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(_.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'      => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(_.+?)\/?$'                     => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3),
        // no daterange + 1 param + orderby native
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(.+?)\/asc\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'  => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&order=asc&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(.+?)\/asc\/?$'                 => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&order=asc',
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'       => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/by\/(.+?)\/?$'                      => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3),
        // no daterange + 1 param w/o orderby
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'                  => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3),
        'filter\/(genre|tag|artist)\/(.+)\/?$'                                  => 'index.php?' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2),


        // with daterange + 0 params + orderby meta
        'filter\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(_.+?)\/asc\/page\/([0-9])\/?$' => 'index.php?datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&order=asc&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4),
        'filter\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(_.+?)\/asc\/?$'                => 'index.php?datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&order=asc',
        'filter\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(_.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'      => 'index.php?datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4),
        'filter\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(_.+)\/?$'                      => 'index.php?datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3),
        // with daterange + 0 params + orderby native
        'filter\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(.+?)\/asc\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'  => 'index.php?datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&order=asc&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4),
        'filter\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(.+?)\/asc\/?$'                 => 'index.php?datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&order=asc',
        'filter\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'       => 'index.php?datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4),
        'filter\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/by\/(.+)\/?$'                       => 'index.php?datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3),
        // with daterange + 0 params w/o orderby
        'filter\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'                  => 'index.php?datelo=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&datehi=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3),
        'filter\/([0-9]{8})\/([0-9]{8})\/?$'                                 => 'index.php',

        // no daterange + 0 params + orderby meta
        'filter\/by\/(_.+?)\/asc\/page\/([0-9])\/?$' => 'index.php?mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&order=asc&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2),
        'filter\/by\/(_.+?)\/asc\/?$'                => 'index.php?mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&order=asc',
        'filter\/by\/(_.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'      => 'index.php?mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2),
        'filter\/by\/(_.+)\/?$'                      => 'index.php?mixmeta=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
        // no daterange + 0 params + orderby native
        'filter\/by\/(.+?)\/asc\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'  => 'index.php?orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&order=asc&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2),
        'filter\/by\/(.+?)\/asc\/?$'                 => 'index.php?orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&order=asc',
        'filter\/by\/(.+?)\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'       => 'index.php?orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2),
        'filter\/by\/(.+)\/?$'                       => 'index.php?orderby=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
        // no daterange + 0 params w/o orderby
        'filter\/page\/([0-9])\/?$'                  => 'index.php?paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
        'filter\/?$'                                 => 'index.php'
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue this is micro-optimisation and your efforts will be better spent elsewhere - an extra 80 rules is a blink in the total WordPress runtime (they're just a `foreach` loop with a `preg_match`).

You are much better off making sure that any custom database tables are designed effectively, your queries are efficient, and that you leverage caching wherever you can.

**Update:** Start off with an [in-depth look at WordPress' cache system](http://wptavern.com/persistent-object-caching). This series on [caching at the page level](http://www.wpexplorer.com/post-series/guide-to-wordpress-caching/) also worth a read.

Comment: I realize this could be a separate question, but do you mind editing your answer to link to some sources that explain how I would effectively leverage caching for filter results pages? It may benefit other people stumbling across this question.

Comment: I don't know, generating the state machine to evaluate a regexp can be expensive. It is a pity php still don't offer a way to cache the state machines. If you have object caching on then it might actually take relatively long time. Agree it is probably early optimization for this question.

Comment: I would still think that parsing ~100 rewrite rules is still only ~1% of a total WordPress request. It's the actual filter system that needs to be TIGHT before OP should start worrying elsewhere.